# Python 3.5 insert sql stored variable

Tags: python, sql-server

I am working on my first Python script to check email then parse out some data then insert into a Microsoft sql database. I am having problems with how to insert the saved variable `t`.

```
import imaplib
import email
import re
import _mssql


m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
m.login("username","password$")
m.select('"Fire_Dispatch"')

result, data = m.search(None, "ALL") # search all email and return uids
if result == 'OK':
    for num in data[0].split():
        result, data = m.fetch(num,"(BODY[TEXT])")
        if result == 'OK':
            email_message = email.message_from_string(data[0]  [1].decode('utf-8'))    # raw email text including headers 
p = str(email_message)
a = re.search("ALLCFD(.*)",p)

t = (a.groups(1))
print (t)

conn = _mssql.connect(server='server', user='username',    password='password', database='CFD_Calls')

conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO calls (call_date_time,call)VALUES('3',t)")

m.close()
m.logout()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide the `t` variable into the sql execution. One way to do this:

```
conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO calls (call_date_time,call) VALUES('3',?)", (t,))
```

I'm assuming `t` will be a string. Note that when provided to the sql command, the variable is enclosed in a tuple. This is because the command expects the argument to be a sequence.

Comment: That doesnt work i get a sql error. it doesnt like the "?"

Comment: What is the traceback? Alternatively, it could be `%s` instead of `?`